# Entity framework and transaction scope

Tags: entity-framework, transactionscope

I say I have the following three methods:

```
DeleteProduct(int productId);
DeleteProductAttributes(int productId);
DeleteProductManufacturers(int productId);
```

I also have a global (within the class) Object context call it _context.
I am wanting each of these methods to work on their own as I need to use them else where. However in the delete product method I want to be able to use transaction scope in case something fails and I get left with a product with no attributes or manufacturer. So my DeleteProduct method looks something like this at the moment

```
public void DeleteProduct(int productId)
{
    if (productId == 0)
        return;
    Product product = GetProductById(productId);
    DeleteProductAttributes(productId);
    DeleteProductManufacturers(productId);
    _context.Products.DeleteObject(product);
}
```

Does anyone have any insight into how I could do this without destroying the structure I have above?

Any help much appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all three methods use the same context stored in `_context` field then they are already in transaction. All data modification (including deletes) are only marked within context and executed in database only when you call `SaveChanges`. `SaveChanges` always does all modifications in a transaction.

Comment: * All three methods use the same context.
* All three methods call savechanges().
* I will post proper code of all three methods

Comment: Sorry cannot edit the above comment. Are you saying that if I run the above method and DeleteProductManufacturers fails then  DeleteProductAttributes will be rolled back?

Comment: If they use single `SaveChanges` then they will all rollback.